# office-addin-lint how to set max warnings?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

For lint you can set max warnings with `--max-warnings N` but it doesn't work for [office-addin-lint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-addin-lint). How can you set the max warnings using [office-addin-lint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-addin-lint)? I don't see anything in the [project documentation](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-Scripts).

Both: `npm run office-addin-lint --max-warnings 0 check` and `npm run office-addin-lint check --max-warnings 0` yield: `error: unknown option '--max-warnings'`

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently a way to set the max warnings on the Office Add-ins linter. The tool would need to be updated to pass that parameter to the underlying eslint.

I'd recommend asking for this feature on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-Scripts/issues).